# add and remove a header of this listView

Tags: android, listview

I have a listView. The content of listView is stored in the list maintained in the adapter.I want to add and remove a header of this listView at click of button. When I add header,I get exception that adapter is already set.Is there any other way?Please help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to call `.addHeader()` and `.addFooter()` before `.setAdapter()` on a ListView. My suggestion is to `modify your adapter to display a header row as a first row`, when needed, and not use .addHeader(). You may have to add a new row-type for this in your adapter. Also, add methods for your adapter that enables you to hide/show this header row, but don't forget to call `.notifyDatasetChanged()` after that.

Answer (score 8):

You have to set the adapter after adding the Header, like this

```
View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null);
ListView listView = getListView();
listView.addHeaderView(header);
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice,
                android.R.id.text1, names));
```

Answer (score 2):

just first set the header and footer on listview then set the adapter.

like, (Remember I only suggest you the procedure the methods may be different then I write here.)

```
 // stuff of header
 listview.addHeaderView(View v);

 //stuff of footer
 listview.addFooterView(View v);

 //stuff of adapter
 listview.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```